# How do I run the react_router examples?

Tags: ubuntu, react-router

I followed the [instructions](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples). I had to 'sudo' the npm install.

Then when I open the browser as instructed I see a nice list of examples.

However, every example fails to run because there is no relevant file in `__build__`. There is a 404 error in the browser debug window to this effect e.g:

```
GET 
http://localhost:8080/__build__/animations.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1ms]
```

I'm new to webpack etc. but have it working with the main react_router installed in a test application. In the cloned repo, it shows a cascade of 'Symbol is not defined' errors.

Looks like I'm missing something in the setup.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a default 14.04 ubuntu OS and the version of node installed was:

```
~ $ node -v
v0.10.37
```

I followed the instructions [here](http://linoxide.com/ubuntu-how-to/setup-node-js-4-0-ubuntu-14-04-15-04/) to upgrade it:

```
~/system/node-v4.0.0-rc.1 $ node -v
v4.0.0-pre
```

With that done, changing to the example folder and invoking `npm start` did the trick.